# What factors affect the tiredness of the drivers in B-Specs?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

The level of the driver increases the resistence of tiredness.

I've heard that the type or power of car could affect too. Is it true?

What other factors affect the tiredness of the drivers in B-Specs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen, lateral acceleration and their physical shape play a role.

Lateral acceleration would be a result of the type of car and the course.